# Exception handling in pure C

Tags: c, exception

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C : How do you simulate an 'exception' ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219438/c-how-do-you-simulate-an-exception)

Hi, I know that exception handling is available in C++ but not in C. But I also read that exception handling is provided from OS side, so isnt there any function for C invoking the same behavior from OS as try catch and throw? Thanks.

Comment: Duplicate: [C : How do you simulate an 'exception'?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219438/), [How do I implement exceptions with nestable try-catch-finally statement with messages in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1779189/), [Exception libraries for C (not C++)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3581818/), [Exception libraries for C (not C++)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410329/) and related: [How are exceptions implemented under the hood?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995734/), [How to throw an exception in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891766/) etc.

Comment: Come on, B.Gen, you're not new here. You know how things work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The C language itself has no support for exception handling.  However a means of exception handling for C does exist on a platform + compiler specific basis.

In windows for example C programs can use SEH exception handling.

- http://www.microsoft.com/msj/0197/Exception/Exception.aspx

I've seen arguments in the past that the C function pair `setjmp` and `longjmp` is exception handling in C.  I consider it closer to the ejection pattern but it's worth investigating

- [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa272905(VS.60).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa272905%28VS.60%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Not in a platform-independent way.  And this would only be for hardware/OS-level exceptions, not SW exceptions.

Answer (score 2):

C provides exceptions in a standard library: setjmp()/longjmp().

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a true, pure, portable C solution.
For Microsoft compilers, you can use __try __except, see [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zazxh1a9(VS.80).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zazxh1a9%28VS.80%29.aspx)